# Game tree with Forest - circle at node not joined to edges

Tags: tikz-trees, forest, game-tree

Using the techniques demonstrated by @marmot (thank you!) at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/453849/game-tree-can-my-code-be-improved/453852#453852), I've produced the following game tree:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\vdisp}[1]{\ensuremath{\begin{pmatrix}#1\end{pmatrix}}}
\newcommand{\red}[1]{\color{red}#1\color{black}}

\begin{center}
    \scriptsize
    \begin{forest}
        for tree={s sep=0.15cm,l sep=1.25cm}
        [,tikz={\fill[](.anchor)circle[radius=1.5pt];}
        [\red{2}
        [{\vdisp{2\\2}}]
        [\red{1}, alias = L
        [{\vdisp{1\\0}}]
        [{\vdisp{0\\1}}] 
        ] 
        ]
        [\red{2}
        [\red{1}, alias = R
        [{\vdisp{0\\3}}]
        [{\vdisp{3\\0}}]
        ]
        [{\vdisp{0\\0}}]
        ]
        ]
        \node[draw,dashed,rounded rectangle,fit=(L) (R)]{};  
    \end{forest}
\end{center}
```

Small adjustment needed: How can I direct connect the edges to the circle at the root node?

**ADDITIONAL:**

If anyone has a suggestion on how to improve the appearance of my payoffs (which have to be displayed in `pmatrix` style, I'd love to hear it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, setting `inner sep` of the root node to `0` does the trick.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\vdisp}[1]{\ensuremath{\begin{pmatrix}#1\end{pmatrix}}}
\newcommand{\red}[1]{\color{red}#1\color{black}}

\begin{center}
    \scriptsize
    \begin{forest}
        for tree={s sep=0.15cm,l sep=1.25cm},
        [,inner sep=0,tikz={\fill[](.anchor)circle[radius=1.5pt];}
        [\red{2}
        [{\vdisp{2\\2}}]
        [\red{1}, alias = L
        [{\vdisp{1\\0}}]
        [{\vdisp{0\\1}}] 
        ] 
        ]
        [\red{2}
        [\red{1}, alias = R
        [{\vdisp{0\\3}}]
        [{\vdisp{3\\0}}]
        ]
        [{\vdisp{0\\0}}]
        ]
        ]
        \node[draw,dashed,rounded rectangle,fit=(L) (R)]{};  
    \end{forest}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

In general, however, it might be best to tell Forest (actually, PGF) that the root node is circular (and `fill` it). The `inner sep` parameter changes the size of the circle (which is otherwise determined by the content, in this case empty).  Set the `outer sep` to empty to connect the edges tightly to the node; or, alternatively, `draw` the node besides `fill`ing it.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\vdisp}[1]{\ensuremath{\begin{pmatrix}#1\end{pmatrix}}}
\newcommand{\red}[1]{\color{red}#1\color{black}}

\begin{center}
    \scriptsize
    \begin{forest}
        for tree={s sep=0.15cm,l sep=1.25cm},
        [,circle,fill,outer sep=0,inner sep=1pt,
        [\red{2}
        [{\vdisp{2\\2}}]
        [\red{1}, alias = L
        [{\vdisp{1\\0}}]
        [{\vdisp{0\\1}}] 
        ] 
        ]
        [\red{2}
        [\red{1}, alias = R
        [{\vdisp{0\\3}}]
        [{\vdisp{3\\0}}]
        ]
        [{\vdisp{0\\0}}]
        ]
        ]
        \node[draw,dashed,rounded rectangle,fit=(L) (R)]{};  
    \end{forest}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I really love and am deeply impressed by your package! +1

Answer (score 1):

Another example to use the [`istgame`](https://ctan.org/pkg/istgame) package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{istgame}

\begin{document}

\begin{istgame}
\tikzset{oval node/.style={ellipse node,draw=none,red}}
\xtdistance{20mm}{10mm}
\istroot(0)+20mm..30mm+
  \istb \istb \endist
\istrooto(1)(0-1){2}
  \istb{}{\binom{2}{2}} \istb \endist
\istrooto(2)(0-2){2}
  \istb \istb{}{\binom{0}{0}} \endist
\istrooto(3)(1-2){1}
  \istb{}{\binom{1}{0}} \istb{}{\binom{0}{1}} \endist
\istrooto(4)(2-1){1}
  \istb{}{\binom{0}{3}} \istb{}{\binom{3}{0}} \endist
\setxtinfosetlayer{main}
\xtInfosetO[dashed](3)(4)(2em)
\end{istgame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: My compliments for your new package `istgame`.